# How can I get data from Goodreads and use it in Telegram Bot API

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've come up with an idea of writing an inline telegram bot and use a Goodreads API for this. But I don't know how to properly extract a book info from Goodreads and put it into special fields in bot api request. I will be so much grateful for helping me with this issue! :)

Comment: This Python wrapper for Goodreads API seems like a good starting point - https://github.com/sefakilic/goodreads.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy, just consume API, store data in the memory, and use it when you need it.

Here is example with Node.js: https://github.com/ro31337/exbot

This app is using API feed to fetch data. You can see how it works by adding  @goa_bot to your Telegram.